# What is the criteria of choosing area in the formula of magnetic flux?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

In the formula for finding electric flux the area is taken as the area that is crossed by electric field
$$\Phi_{E} =\int \vec{E} \cdot \vec{\mathrm {d}S}$$

But in the formula of finding **magnetic flux**, **Is there a criteria or definition for taking area?** , as there are cases where we use different ways of taking it.

In some cases we take the area that a body (like wire) crosses while moving in a magnetic field while in some cases (in loop) we take it as the the area enclosed by the loop.

Please elaborate your reasoning.

Comment: The only thing you must notice is the area pierced by the magnetic field. When it is piercing the cross section of a cylindrical conductor or when it is piercing area enclosed by a loop. That is it. No special rules as such.

Comment: What if a loop is considered and no piercing is happening at all??

Comment: Then it would not matter however you move the loop, until and unless magnetic field lines pierce, the flux would remain zero. It is a point to note that the integral works on the area through which  magnetic field lines pierce : $\displaystyle  \Phi_{B} = \int_{S} \vec{B} \cdot \vec{\mathrm {d}S}.$

Comment: No, there is no such criteria. We can calculate flux (electric or magnetic) through any area whatever. Which area we choose depends on what we are trying to calculate.

Comment: There is no such criteria; see [Normal Vector in Electric Flux and Gauss's Law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/658652/203278). The concept of flux depends on three things (in my answer there, I emphasize the third point more, but the second point is just as important). So, it is up to you to decide what you want to calculate.